# Leaning against a window

Tags: windows, bedroom

My bed is right up against a window. I prefer to lean against something and sit in bed while working. Is it safe for me to lean against a closed glass window? Is there any way I could fashion something that would put less stress on the window?

Comment: I think [headboards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headboard_(furniture)) are the standard solution.

Comment: Can you just swap the head and foot of the bed and lean against whatever's at the other end?

Answer (score 1):

Glass isn't very flexible and you stand a pretty good chance of breaking the glass, which could injure you directly, or allow you to fall out the window.

You didn't say how far the window is off the ground outside, but presumably you don't want to fall out the window unexpectedly amidst shards of glass that could end up sticking out of you at comically tragic angles.

You also didn't mention whether the window in question is made of plate glass (brittle, shatters easily, ends up in big pointy shards) or some kind of safety glass (specially treated, often has some kind of polycarbonate material sandwiched in the glass or coating one or both sides). Safety glass is somewhat less brittle, and tends to break into smaller, rounder pieces that won't impale you. Automobile windows are made out of safety glass.

So that's my way of saying no, I probably wouldn't make a habit of leaning on the window.

If you can't pick up an actual headboard for you bed as @Tester101 suggested, maybe you can just lie with your head at the other end of the bed and lean against whatever's on that end (a wall?). Or maybe you could screw a few wood slats across the lower half of the window and lean against those.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to preserve the view through the window?  I.e. no block it off with plywood.

I would suggest combining layers of plexiglass.  In my experience, when the various types of plexiglass break, they don't produce as sharp stab-you-through-the-ribs shards as glass.

There are two properties that you want to look for when selecting the type of plexiglass (there are many different types): Its **UV resistance** and its **flexibility**.

**UV resistance** is needed because the ultraviolet rays from the sun typically degrades plastic (plexiglass).  This degrading can be yellowing or making it more brittle, etc.

**Flexibility** is somewhat contrary to what you're probably thinking.  The harder something is the less able it is to stand up to impact loads such as you leaning back (which may not sound like a big impact, but it is an impact) and moving around.  When something can't flex, it will shatter.

I recommend a sufficiently thick (maybe double layered) piece of flexible plexiglass so that it won't bend excessively when you lean against it, but also has the ability to flex when needed.

Comment: Seems like a lot of work just to be able to sit up in bed...  ;-)